# Swift 5 crashes due to memory error at 400MB used memory

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, viewcontroller

I have a learning app where I chain multiple ViewControllers together using the function:

```
let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
weak var levelCompletedViewController = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "levelCompletedViewController") as? LevelCompletedViewController
levelCompletedViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(levelCompletedViewController!, animated: false)
```

It always crashes after 24 viewControllers (I need 32) due to the error:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

On the 32nd viewController, I would call dismiss() on all, such that the deinit function gets called. Also, each time in viewDidDisappear I delete all images and other memory-intensive variables.

**My memory indicator shows that it never rises above 400MB.** However, my application crashes every time exactly at 24 screens. (I want 32)

I use [weak self] in closures and have zombie objects disabled. and no infinite for loop or something similar, since the screen types are random and always crash at 24.

Is there a trick to fix this problem, like for example calling deinit every time I move from one viewController to another by resetting the root viewController or something similar?

**EDIT:**

As Sweeper mentioned in the comments, there would also be the possibility to just dismiss a screen before presenting another screen. Nevertheless, in this case, my custom transition from right to left would not work:

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
transition.type = CATransitionType.push
transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You likely do not need all 32 VCs to be in memory at the same time, as you have said "like for example calling deinit everytime I move from one viewController to another". What are you trying to do here? Why are you presenting 32 VCs in a chain?

Comment: The thing is, after finishing all 32 Screens, I need to get back to the initial one. And the only way to do it (as far as I know) is to chain all of the VCs and then dismiss them all. Do you know a better solution?

Comment: You already said that in the question. Can you *please* add some additional context about what these 32 VCs are? How about rather than presenting them on top of one another, you dismiss the first before presenting the second, dismiss the second before presenting the third?

Comment: The animation doesn't look smooth when I dismiss the first and then show the second. I want the last screen swiped to the left and the new screen from the right. There is no smooth animation when I first dismiss and then show the other.

Comment: If *that's* the reason why you are presenting 32 VCs in a chain, then *that's* your real problem. Edit your question to ask about that instead.

Comment: in the viewSidAppear of  view controller you could get the viewControllers or navigation controller . If you have more than 3 view controllers the you remove second item and set this new array as the new list for the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ptit Xav thank you for that comment it really solved my problem.

All I did was:

```
var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
viewControllers?.remove(at: 1)
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = viewControllers ?? []
```